# Find co-ordinates of A.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, quadrilateral

$ABCD$ is a rhombus . Diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $M$.
$BD=2AC$
 $D\rightarrow(1,1)$ and $M\rightarrow(2,-1)$
Find the co-ordinates of $A$.

Comment: I tries finding AM which came out to be sqroot(5)/2.Then I found DA which is 5/2 . I tried forming an equation with center as D and radius as 5/2 . This circle intersects the line AC whose equation came out to be 2y-x+2=0 . Which gives the two co-ordinates of A

Comment: Please do not delete your question once it received an answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you provided in your comment. Such context belongs in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $DM$ we obtain:
$$m_{DM}=\frac{1+1}{1-2}=-2,$$ which says the equation of $AC$ it's
$$y+1=\frac{1}{2}(x-2)$$ or
$$y=\frac{1}{2}x-2.$$
Now, let $A\left(x,\frac{1}{2}x-2\right)$.

Thus, since $$AM=\frac{1}{2}DM=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(1-2)^2+1+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt5,$$ we obtain:
$$(x-2)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}x-1\right)^2=\frac{5}{4}$$ or
$$(x-2)^2=1,$$ which gives $x=3$ or $x=1$ and we obtain:
$$A\left(3,-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ or $$A\left(1,-\frac{3}{2}\right).$$

Comment: so sorry , it is actually BD=2AC

Comment: I fixed. See now.